# Can't find window builder on ubuntu

Tags: java, programming

I am searching for [window builder in eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running the official Eclipse version, go to Help -> Install Software. From there you can select a repository for the applications specific to your version and you can search for Window Builder.
Just click install and reboot Eclipse.

Then you can create new Window Builder classes with your Create New and Open With menus.

This was tested on Eclipse Luna Java EE on Ubuntu 14.10.